# SQL select all if parameter is null else return specific item

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to write the following script so that it returns all products if the ProductID variable is null ? And return a specific product when the product it is not null. 
What I have so far:

```
DECLARE @productID INT = NULL

SELECT
    ProductID,
    ProductName,
    ProductDesc 
FROM
    product 
WHERE
    ProductID = @productID
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use case statement:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName,ProductDesc 
FROM product 
WHERE ProductID = CASE WHEN @productID IS NULL THEN ProductID ELSE @productID END
```

Or IIF() function if you’re using SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName,ProductDesc 
FROM product 
WHERE ProductID =IIF(@productID IS NULL, ProductID, @productID )
```

Comment: wow didnt know 2012 had IIF function in it, I just cant wait for my company to upgarde to 2012

Answer (score 18):

Why not just:

```
DECLARE @productID INT = NULL

SELECT ProductID, ProductName,ProductDesc 
FROM   product 
WHERE  ProductID = @productID
OR     @productID IS NULL;
```

Here a [demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e77e9/5) with NULL and a value for @productID

Comment: This generalises much more nicely. For instance if you want to use a range of values when `@productId IS NULL`, you can do `WHERE ProductId = @ProductId OR (@ProductId IS NULL AND ProductId BETWEEN @Min and @Max)`.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
DECLARE @productID INT = NULL

SELECT 
    ProductID,
    ProductName,
    ProductDesc 
FROM
    product 
WHERE 
    ProductID = isnull(@productID,ProductID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Performance is a incredibly better when using `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName,ProductDesc 
FROM product 
WHERE ProductID = CASE WHEN @productID IS NULL THEN ProductID ELSE @productID END
```

`ISNULL()` prevents the optimizer using an index on that column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    ProductName,
    ProductDesc 
FROM
    product 
WHERE
    ProductID = CASE WHEN @productID IS NULL THEN ProductID ELSE @productID END
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "" is not recognized as `NULL` I used value

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName,ProductDesc 
FROM product 
WHERE ProductID =IIF(@productID =1, ProductID, @productID )
```

In my code:

```
 MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@productID").Value = 1
```