# The sql query should select all rows if variables $whereEmail and $whereNotEmail are empty or null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

The following query do not select any row if variable $whereEmail or variable $whereNotEmail or both of them are empty.

```
$whereEmail = "'abc@gmail.com','def@hotmail.com'";
$whereNotEmail = "'u2u@xyz.com','u3u@xyz.com'";
$result = $mSearch->dao->query(sprintf('
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE email IN (%s)
AND email NOT IN (%s)
', $whereEmail, $whereNotEmail ));
```

The email addresses in variables $whereEmail and $whereNotEmail are stored using a php function, in some cases they are left empty or null.

I expect if both the variables $whereEmail and $whereNotEmail are empty the query should select all rows from the table.

Similarly, I expect if variable $whereEmail is empty the query should select all rows in the table except those where email addresses are in variable $whereNotEmail.

Similarly, I expect if variable $whereNotEmail is empty the query should select all rows where email addresses are in variable $whereEmail.

Answer (score 0):

// you have to set condition where whereEmail not empty and whereNotEmail hopefully this works

```
$whereEmail = "'abc@gmail.com','def@hotmail.com'";
$whereNotEmail = "'u2u@xyz.com','u3u@xyz.com'"; 
if($whereEmail != ''){
$result = $mSearch->dao->query(sprintf('
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE email IN (%s)
', $whereEmail ));
}else{
$result = $mSearch->dao->query(sprintf('
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE email NOT IN (%s)
', $whereNotEmail ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I expect if both the variables $whereEmail and $whereNotEmail are
>   empty the query should select all rows from the table.

NO, query understand SQL language construct and not PHP and thus you will have to check and do accordingly. If I were you then will validate if both the list are empty or not. If empty then then pop-up a validation message probably else will pass it in to the query. (OR) if any of the list is empty then you can as well waive off that condition from your query.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357990/sql-select-all-if-parameter-is-null-else-return-specfic-item will it be helpful?

Comment: @Syed, no it won't be since that's checking for SQLParameter and not a PHP variable. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: No, is it possible to convert the PHP variable to SQL Parameter?

Comment: @Syed, simple answer: NO

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you can try the following approach: start building a query that selects all rows and add conditions if those email arrays are not empty

```
    $whereEmail = array('abc@gmail.com','def@hotmail.com');
    $whereNotEmail = array('u2u@xyz.com','u3u@xyz.com');

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1';
    if(!empty($whereEmail)) {
            $validEmailsString = implode('","', $whereEmail);
            $query .= ' AND email IN ("'.$validEmailsString.'")';
    }

    if (!empty($whereNotEmail)) {
            $invalidEmailsString = implode('","', $whereNotEmail);
            $query .= ' AND email NOT IN ("'.$invalidEmailsString.'")';
    }

    print $query;

    $result = $mSearch->dao->query($query);
```