# Manually enter a parameter value or All by default in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to create a parameter in SSRS where the user has the option to either manually enter an id or else have the report return all records.  This is how the parameter currently looks:[image]

In this situation the user can manually enter one providerid, which works.  But is it possible for the user to leave the providerid parameter blank and then by default the report will run for all records?

The providerid parameter is populated with a stored procedure:

```
    Select distinct cast(providerid as varchar(25)) as providerid
    from Table A
```

I've read other threads on here that appear similar, but I can't figure out how to get this work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select all if parameter is null else return specfic item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357990/sql-select-all-if-parameter-is-null-else-return-specfic-item)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is:

Add another item to your drop list called ALL with a special value

```
Select distinct  
cast(providerid as varchar(25)) as providerid,
cast(providerid as varchar(25)) as providerLabel
from Table A
union all
select -1, 'All Providers'
```

Make sure you assign label and value correctly.

Allow for this special value in your stored proc:

```
where ...
and  (providerid = @providerid or @providerid = -1)
and ...
```

Comment: I'm still not getting this to work properly.  The parameter box shouldn't have anything populated. It should either be blank, upon which it will return all records, or the user can manually enter an id.

Comment: If it must be blank then replace “all providers” with “”. Please explain your issue clearly if that doesn’t solve it.

Comment: I'm thinking the issue may be in how I'm populating the SSRS parameter box.  Not sure what to do here.  I left Available Values blank. For Default Values I chose =" ".  In my SP I added a UNION ALL of Select -1, ' '.  But logically that means if the drop box is left blank the value will =-1, which doesn't return anything.  I need -1 to return All values.

Comment: Thats what part 2 of my answer explains (albeit not in too much detail). You need to to alter the report filters so that if -1 is passed, it will return everything. This is standard practice in SSRS. I assumed the stored proc was what was populating the report but maybe I misunderstood

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Again, this is a proven and reliable way to implement this functionality

Comment: I did.  I had a coworker explain exactly how to do this.  I needed to create an expression in the SSRS parameter box that converts the Id to a string and check its length: =IIF(cstr(trim(Parameters!providerid.Value)).Length = 0, -100, cstr(Parameters!providerid.Value)).  Then in the stored proc I did the "select -100 OR xxx".  It was a bit more complicated than simply using a -1 or -100 in this case.  I don't see why I got a -1 for this question as none of the other answers on this forum were specific to my needs.