# querying with nulls and lists

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016, cfqueryparam

I have

```
QueryExecute(

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.pages
    WHERE ID IN ( :id )
    ...
   ,
   {
       id : { value = rc.id, cfsqltype : "cf_sql_integer, list : true }
   }
```

Almost all the time this works. The thing is `rc.id` can be blank. If it is blank, then all IDs should be matched. I am stuck on how to do this

Comment: To be clear... Is this the sort of thing you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357990/sql-select-all-if-parameter-is-null-else-return-specific-item

Comment: (Edit) It's not possible with just a single `IN` clause. I find the cleanest way is to build the sql statement conditionally, i.e. append that condition to the `where` clause only if the parameter isn't empty. The `or` approach mentioned in the link does work, but it'd require more complex code + sql that's less readable IMO.

Comment: @TRose a lot like that but with an IN

Comment: If you want to write it that way, it requires two conditions. The first being the current IN clause and the second should return true when the variable is blank. For example `where ( column IN ( :idList ) OR :copyIDList = '' ) ... more `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different options here.

**1) You can manipulate the query string to only include the IN statement when the variable is not empty.**

How you go about that really really depends on the rest of the query and how you would like to do this.

```
<cfset sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM dbo.pages" />
<cfif len(rc.id)>
    <cfset sqlstr &= " WHERE ID IN ( :id )" />
</cfif>
```

You could build up more cleanly with conditional output...

```
WHERE #len(rc.id) ? "ID IN ( :id )" : ""#
```

To avoid having to worry about whether WHERE/AND/OR is included one little trick is to include a clause that will always pass (or never in the case of ORing)

```
WHERE 1=1 
    #len(rc.id) ? "AND ID IN ( :id )" : ""#
    AND ...
```

**2) Pass the parameter twice and perform the check in the database**

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.pages
WHERE (len(':id') = 0 OR ID IN ( :id ))
...

-- note: this may be problematic if CF is passing null when blank
```

or just the length

```
    QueryExecute(

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.pages
    WHERE (:idlen > 0 OR ID IN ( :id ))
    ...
   ,
   {
       id : { value = rc.id, cfsqltype : "cf_sql_integer, list : true },
       idlen : { value = len(rc.id), cfsqltype : "cf_sql_integer" }
   }
```

Comment: *include a clause that will always pass* ... or if the clause has more conditions (looks like it does), that should always be included, just move them to the top of the `where` clause.

Comment: @Ageax yeah, good point. Meant that tip for more complex cases :)

Comment: Yep. Still a good trick to know, in the event that all of the conditions are optional.

Comment: @DanRoberts While your len(rc.id) condition meet false that time the issue will occur in queryParam parts. Because you have check the condition in WHERE  sections only not queryParam section. So I hope you have to check the same conditions in queryparam too.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've given sample code about making the queryparam conditional too. For testing purpose I've created some default parameters and values

```
<cfparam name="id" default="1,2,3,4,5,6">
```

Set the query details as a string and save it to another variable as @danRoberts mentioned above.

```
<cfset MyQry = "SELECT * FROM pages ">
```

Check if the **rc.id** value is blank. If it isn't, append the `IN` clause.

```
<cfif len(rc.id) >
    <cfset MyQry &= " WHERE id IN ( :id ) ">
</cfif>
```

For reference, I've also added some extra operators.

```
<cfset MyQry &= " limit 10 ">
```

Next, create a new query based on **new** operator

```
<cfset qry = new Query( datasource ='yourDataSource' , sql = MyQry) >
```

Afterward, add a queryParam for the `:ID`, if the **rc.id** is not blank

```
<cfif len(rc.id) >
<cfset qry.addParam( name="id", value="#rc.id#",cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar",list='true') >
</cfif>
```

**Note :** When using the `IN`operator, you should set 
**list='true'** for the queryParam.

Then you execute the query, like below

```
<cfset Result = qry.execute().getResult() >
<cfdump var="#Result#" />
```

The `WHERE` clause with the queryParam will execute only when the rc.ID contains a value.

Comment: I don't like the idea of migrating form `QueryExecute` to `new Query`.