# How do I create a single query for multiple optional search parameters in a parameterized query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, web-applications

I'm working on a Report form where a user inputs multiple values on textboxes and I take those values and I perform parameterized query search.

My current issue is a report form that has 8 total parameters but has a minimum requirement of three values being: Store_ID, From_date and To_Date. What I want to do is to have a single query that performs a search with the given values. So that I wont have to create cases or if else statement for each possible combination of those 8 parameters.

I would appreciate if someone can provide an example of on how to do that.

For additional context is for a report form Web application build using Visual Studio .NET with Visual basic.

**EDIT**: I made the modifications to the query as suggested in the comments.

My current query works but only if all the values are provided. But if I don't add one of the optional query parameters I get the following error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

I suspect this error is because I didn't assign a value to a parameter.
Or that perhaps the  `AND H.Rgst_ID IS NULL` statement might be causing a SQL error and doesn't perform the search.

How can I fix this error so that my query accepts blank/null inputs?

This is my current code:

**SQLControl**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class SQLControl

```
Private ReadOnly ConStr As String = "String"
Private DBCmd As SqlCommand

'Query Parameters
Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

'This generates a blank sqlclient class with the deafult connection string
Public Sub New()
End Sub

'Allow connection string override
Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
    ConStr = connectionString
End Sub

'Execute Query Sub
Public Function ExecQuery(query As String) As DataTable

    Dim DBDT = New DataTable
    Using DBCon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            DBCmd As New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        Params.Clear()
        DBCon.Open()
        DBDT.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return DBDT

End Function

'Add Params
Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)  
    Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub

End Class
```

Web Form code:

```
Protected Sub ExecuteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click
    Dim StoreID As Integer
    Dim TransID As Integer
    Dim RgstID As Integer
    Dim FromDate As DateTime
    Dim ToDate As DateTime
    Dim DiscCD As Integer 'This is selected from the item list 
    Dim DiscPercent As Double
    Dim DiscAmount As Double

    'The minimum required search paraeters are Store_ID, From_Date and To_Date. The rest of the parameters are optional

    'StoreID Validation
    If Not Integer.TryParse(StoreIDTextbox.Text, StoreID) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter Store ID.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'FromDateValidation
    If Not DateTime.TryParse(FromDateTextbox.Text, FromDate) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter from date")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'ToDateValidation
    If Not DateTime.TryParse(ToDateTextbox.Text, ToDate) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter to date.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Integer.Parse(RegisterIDTextbox.Text, RgstID)
    Integer.Parse(TransactionIDTextbox.Text, TransID)
    Integer.Parse(ListBox1.SelectedValue, DiscCD)
    Double.Parse(DiscountPercentTextbox.Text, DiscPercent)
    Double.Parse(DiscountAmtTextbox.Text, DiscAmount)

    Dim pct As Double
    pct = DiscPercent / 100
    Dim amt As Double
    amt = DiscAmount * -1

    'Adds parameter to the query
    SQL.AddParam("@Str_ID", StoreID)
    SQL.AddParam("@FromDate", FromDate)
    SQL.AddParam("@ToDate", ToDate)
    SQL.AddParam("@Rgst_ID", RgstID)
    SQL.AddParam("@Trans_ID", TransID)
    SQL.AddParam("@DiscType", DiscCD)
    SQL.AddParam("@DisPct", pct)
    SQL.AddParam("@DisAmt", amt)

    Dim dt As DataTable

    Try
        dt = SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT H.Str_ID, H.Rgst_ID, H.Tran_ID, L.Tran_LN_Num, H.Bus_DT, H.Emp_ID, H.Cust_ID, LD.Auth_Emp_ID, L.Ext_Prc, LD.Disc_Amt, D.Descr, LD.Disc_Pct, LD.DisC_CD
                                FROM twOLTP.dbo.Transaction_Header H 
                                INNER JOIN twOLTP.dbo.LN_Detail L ON (H.Str_ID = L.Str_ID AND H.Rgst_ID = L.Rgst_ID AND H.Tran_ID = L.Tran_ID)
                                INNER JOIN twOLTP.dbo.LN_Discount LD ON (L.Str_ID = LD.Str_ID AND L.Rgst_ID = LD.Rgst_ID AND L.Tran_ID = LD.Tran_ID AND L.Tran_Ln_Num = LD.Tran_Ln_Num)
                                LEFT JOIN twOLTP.dbo.Discount D ON (LD.Disc_CD = D.Disc_CD)
                                WHERE (H.Str_ID = @Str_ID) 
                                AND (H.Bus_DT >= @FromDate) 
                                AND (H.Bus_DT <= @ToDate) 
                                AND (H.Rgst_ID IS NULL OR H.Rgst_ID = @Rgst_ID)
                                AND (H.Tran_ID IS NULL OR H.Tran_ID = @Trans_ID)
                                AND (LD.DisC_CD IS NULL OR LD.DisC_CD = @DiscType)
                                AND (LD.Disc_Pct IS NULL OR LD.Disc_Pct = @DisPct)
                                AND (LD.Disc_Amt IS NULL OR LD.Disc_Amt = @DisAmt) ")

    Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

**EDIT** I was able to solve the problem

For my query to accept blank/null inputs i had t do the following.

```
WHERE ((H.Rgst_ID = @Rgst_ID) Or (@Rgst_ID Is NULL Or @Rgst_ID = ''))
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I suggest you peruse [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). A simple approach for the optional parameters is `AND (@Parameter IS NULL OR SomeColumn = @Parameter)` plus an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` query hint for performance.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357990/sql-select-all-if-parameter-is-null-else-return-specific-item will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause might look like this... the first three params are required, the others are optional

```
WHERE
Store_ID = @Store_ID
AND
From_date = @From_date
AND
To_Date = @To_Date
AND
ISNULL(@param4,param_name_4) = param_name_4
AND
ISNULL(@param5,param_name_5) = param_name_5
AND
ISNULL(@param6,param_name_6) = param_name_6
AND
ISNULL(@param7,param_name_7) = param_name_7
AND
ISNULL(@param8,param_name_8) = param_name_8
```

Comment: I'm kind of new here, curious why there was a downvote. I explained the approach for the OP, not just a link or "go read this article". Are you looking for a sample of the VB code that would accomplish this?

Comment: I wish the downvoter had commented. I am interested in this usage of ISNULL. Can you tell me where it is documented?

Comment: Perhaps the downvote is due to your usage of the from/to parameters - which usually define a range for a single column and not specific values for different columns. Usually the bigger issue is that this approach tends to perform poorly as the links explain - though it does work correctly. And since someone has asked, a little explanation of how the isnull usage works would improve the suggestion greatly.

Comment: The biggest problem here, in my opinion, is the lack of SARGability. Although it'll work, it could (will) perform awfully, as the RDBMS has no opportunity to use any indexes.

Comment: I had not thought about the fact that it is a date range, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan mentioned in the comments under the question, you want to be able to maintain SARGability here. For a simple query, this means you can use an `OR` with an `IS NULL` on the parameter like this below:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE StoreID = @StoreID
  AND FromDate = @FromDate
  AND ToDate = @ToDate
  AND (OtherColumn = @OtherParameter OR @OtherParameter IS NULL)
  AND (AnotherColumn = @AnotherParameter OR @AnotherParameter IS NULL)
  AND (SomeColumn = @SomeParameter OR @SomeParameter IS NULL)
  AND (YetAnotherColumn = @YetAnotherParameter OR @YetAnotherParameter IS NULL)
  AND (FinalColumn = @FinalParameter OR @FinalParameter IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

You need to, however, ensure you have `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as SQL Server would generate a single plan based on this query. This is bad as the query has many different ways of running, and so a plan where 1 parameter has a non-`NULL` value would be vastly different to where none of them do. `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` forces the data engine to regenerate the plan as a result.

This, however, can come at a cost, and sometimes it better to stick to the "older" method us using dynamic SQL to generate the statement. This means that different statements are run, depending on what parameters have non-`NULL` values.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ...' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.YourTable YT' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE YT.StoreID = @StoreID' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND YT.FromDate = @FromDate' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND YT.ToDate = @ToDate' + @CRLF +
           CASE WHEN @OtherParameter IS NOT NULL THEN N'  AND YT.OtherColumn = @OtherParameter' + @CRLF + END +
           CASE WHEN @AnotherParameter IS NOT NULL THEN N'  AND YT.AnotherColumn = @AnotherParameter' + @CRLF + END +
           CASE WHEN @SomeParameter IS NOT NULL THEN N'  AND YT.SomeColumn = @SomeParameter' + @CRLF + END +
           CASE WHEN @YetAnotherParameter IS NOT NULL THEN N'  AND YT.YetAnotherColumn = @YetAnotherParameter' + @CRLF + END +
           CASE WHEN @FinalParameter IS NOT NULL THEN N'  AND YT.FinalColumn = @FinalParameter' + @CRLF + END + N';';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL,
                       N'@OtherParameter int, @AnotherParameter varchar(30), @SomeParameter date, @YetAnotherParameter decimal(12,2), @FinalParameter tinyint', 
                       @OtherParameter,
                       @AnotherParameter,
                       @SomeParameter,
                       @YetAnotherParameter,
                       @FinalParameter;
```

Notice you need to declare all the parameters in the 2nd parameter for `sys.sp_executesql` and still pass them all, but if they have the value `NULL` then the executed query won't use them in the `WHERE`.