# SELECT ALL RECORDS WHEN GUID IS null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this Where Clause in my SP

```
FROM Product p
    INNER JOIN ProductCategory cat ON cat.ProductCategoryId = p.ProductCategoryId
    LEFT JOIN SubCategory sub ON sub.SubCategoryId = p.SubCategoryId
    LEFT JOIN ProductCount pc ON p.ProductId = pc.ProductId
WHERE p.ProductCategoryId = COALESCE(@CategoryId, p.ProductCategoryId)
    AND pc.GeneratedOn BETWEEN @FromDate AND DATEADD(MS, 3, @ToDate)
    AND p.OrgName = @OrgName
```

where my @CategoryId is Guid and when I set it as null like `[dbo].[sample] null, '<insert fromDate>', '<insert toDate>', '<insert orgname>` it selects all rows/records with Guid value.
what I want is to select all rows even Guid/p.ProductCategoryId  = 0x0 / '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

Comment: Look up "Catch-all queries" or "kitchen sink queries"

Comment: sorry for the late reply, Im trying to figure out the catch-all queries, but I dont get in, and i tried it like `(p.ProductCategoryId = CASE WHEN @CategoryId IS NULL THEN p.ProductCategoryId ELSE @CategoryId END)` nothing happens, same result

Comment: Use proper boolean logic, show in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358196/2029983). `WHERE (YourColumn = @YourParameter OR @YourParameter IS NULL)`. I also, however, recommend reading [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [An updated Kitchen-sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: `**INNER** JOIN ProductCategory cat ON cat.ProductCategoryId = p.ProductCategoryId`
Change to:
`**LEFT** JOIN ProductCategory cat ON cat.ProductCategoryId = p.ProductCategoryId`

solved my problem, not connected in operators